# Clear the JTextField by clicking JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I was searching the internet to find a way to clear multiple `JTextField` controls by one click, but finally I reached to write this code, It is working fine with me, but I don't know if if there is a better way to writ such code different than what I wrote.

```
int i;
String[] a = {txtUserId.getText(), txtUserName.getText(), txtMobile.getText()};
String s = "";
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    s = txtUserId.getText().substring(txtUserId.getText().length());
    s = txtUserName.getText().substring(txtUserId.getText().length());
     s = txtMobile.getText().substring(txtUserId.getText().length());
    txtUserId.setText(s);
    txtUserName.setText(s);
    txtMobile.setText(s);
}
```

It cleared all text fields.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
txtUserId.setText("");
txtUserName.setText("");
txtMobile.setText("");
```

etc. for each field that you want to empty when the button is clicked. I'm a bit confused as to why you are writing to 's', as you are constantly overwriting the value it contains, and then setting all three txt objects' text equal to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do txtUserId.setText(""), etc